# How can I print a user selected document?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to select a file using a file dialog and then print the selected file using the `PrintDocument.Print` method.

Below is some code which is a partial implementation of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
     using System;
     using System.Drawing.Printing;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Windows.Forms;


     namespace InstalledAndDefaultPrinters
     {
     class Program
     {


     static void Main(string[] args)
     {   
        string filename="";
        foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            Console.WriteLine(printer);
        var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The default printer is: {0}", printerSettings.PrinterName));

        Console.WriteLine(printerSettings.PrintFileName); 
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Open File Dialog";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\ ";
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        fdlg.ShowDialog();
        Console.WriteLine(fdlg.Title);
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = String.Copy(fdlg.FileName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(filename);

        PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pd_doc = new PrintDocument();
        printdg.ShowDialog();
        if (printdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
```

It is at this point that I would like to print the selected file.

```
            pd_doc.Print();
        }       
    }
```

The code I have above clearly does not do what I need. What alternative approach might steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You can solve that using following code snippet.It works as you want.

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();
            if (printdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
                pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
                pd.Print();
                pd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\therath\Desktop\372\a.jpg");
            // You can replace your logic @ here to load the image or whatever you want
            Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pd` be assigned to the item that `printdg` selected?

Comment: @Crud hey , dont u think that system.drawing.image is only for images??

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray i think system.drawing.image is only for images..what u say brother?

Comment: @UmairAmin, what kind of document are your trying to print?

Comment: @SuperPrograman word file, pdf files images... excel..all that can be prinred